# Posting to wordpress.com blog through the command line

Tags: command-line, wordpress, blogging

I have a wordpress.com blog. I typically post on the blog through the web interface. I have been trying to discover a means to post on the website through the command line. My desired workflow is this:

1. Type the blog post in a text editor in markdown
2. Convert the markdown to html
3. Run a command on the command line to upload said post in html to the wordpress.com blog.

I downloaded wp-cli from . I went through the manual but I have not been able to figure out how to use wp-cli to post on my wordpress.com blog. It seems that wp-cli can be used only if one controls the hosting of the blog.

**Edited to provide more details as requested:**

1. I use linux and I have a blog on .wordpress.com
2. I compose my blogposts with vi and convert them to html with pandoc
3. I am looking for a command line solution i.e. a command I can run in a terminal which will upload this html post onto my blog at .wordpress.com
4. I downloaded wp-cli but as I went through the manual but I have not been able to figure out how to use wp-cli to post on my wordpress.com blog. It seems that wp-cli can be used only if one controls the hosting of the blog. Can I use wp-cli or is there some other solution?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: ***"4. I downloaded wp-cli "*** It won't work.  `wp-cli` is intended to be used locally.  It can be installed on the remote server but then one would need to SSH in to said server to use.   See [use wp-cli to connect to remote WordPress installation](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-wp-cli-to-connect-to-a-remote-wordpress-installation/ "https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-wp-cli-to-connect-to-a-remote-wordpress-installation/")

Answer (score 0):

I use [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation-and-updates/) + [Newman](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003703325-How-do-I-install-Newman-) + [Application Passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/). I'm on Windows but I am pretty sure you can do the same thing on Linux.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though this thread is old, I wanted to chime in with some tips that might help you. First off, I totally get why you want to post to your WordPress.com blog through the command line - it can make things much faster and more efficient.
Now, to answer your question, wp-cli is mainly used for self-hosted WordPress sites, but there are still a few ways to post to a WordPress.com blog from the command line. One option is to use the WordPress REST API, which allows you to make HTTP requests to your WordPress.com site. Also, you can read here about [what type of websites are there](https://crowdo.net/blog/types-of-websites/) and draw your conclusions. It sounds like you have a pretty specific use case, but don't worry - there's definitely a solution out there for you.

Comment: Welcome to SU. This isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. I removed everything that's _not_ an answer - unfortunately that was most of it, and what's left isn't really very helpful. You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777374/edit) the answer to explain how exactly `wp-cli` can be used to post to wordpress.com blog.  Please see the [guidelines for answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help). Please check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), the Help and some older questions with accepted answers to learn how this works.

Comment: Kindly list the "few ways to post to a WordPress.com blog from the command line"